# Error during testing chained properties execution in javascrip - jest

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, jestjs

i have function *"login"* which is ended by this execution:

```
res.status(202).json({ token, userId: user._id.toString() });
```

In test i mocking res object like this:

```
const res = {
  status: jest.fn(),
  json: jest.fn(),
};
```

but i get *TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined*.

When i delete status() execution in *"login"* function & leave only json(), error is not thrown.

I'm using Jest for testing.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, hope it will help for somebody.
In test, res object should looks like this:

```
const res = {
  status: jest.fn(arg => res),
  json: jest.fn(arg => {}),
};
```

The status property have to return object which contains json method (res object in this case).